# Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence of pos. real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 0$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, real-numbers

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 0$

Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = 0$. (Warning: Be careful not to assume that
$(a_n)$ even converges!)

Why would assuming $a_n$ converges change the problem, would it make it easier, and if so how?

Also, I am using the epsilon proof but I think I am having trouble just understanding how to manipulate the epsilon proof to my usage. I asked my TA about this problem and I was given the advice that

$\frac{a_{n+k}}{a_n+1}$ < $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ < $\epsilon$

$\frac{a_{n+k}}{a_n}$ < $\epsilon^k$ < $\epsilon$

anything after $a_n$ is less than 1.

I don't see how this ties to $a_n$. Any explanation in the right direction is appreciated. I want to understand this thoroughly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 0$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n} =0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113399/if-lim-n-to-infty-fraca-n1a-n-0-show-that-lim-n-to-inftya-n) - found through using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7Ba_n%7D%3D0%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%7Ba_n%7D%3D0%24&p=1). Note I actually first found [Limit of ratio goes to zero](/q/3992923), which was closed as a duplicate of this other question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you for the approacho search tool. I was just made aware of the communities policy on low quality questions and duplicate questions. My apologies.

Comment: You're welcome, and also welcome to Math SE. There's really no need to apologize since many of us, including myself sometimes, don't first check for duplicates before posting a question or answer. Since you're aware now, you can use tools like Approach0, the site's search, etc., to search for existing duplicate posts before writing your question or answer. FYI, a good source to learn about the available ways to search (including about using Approach0) is [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/602049).

Comment: I swear, Approach0 will get you a lot of answers : people often ask me why I haven't asked too many questions here, and the answer is : Approach0!